# How to set up a reverse ssh tunnel on a Vps in the cloud?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

When I try to open a forward tunnel on my Vps in the cloud, it works:

```
ssh -p 22 -i mykey user@vps-public-ip -L 10000:vps-private-ip:80
```

Then my local web browser shows the page on the Vps by typing the address `http://localhost:10000`

But the reverse version doesn't work:

```
ssh -p 22 -i mykey user@vps-public-ip -R 10000:localhost:22
```

The goal would be to connect to my Pc at home from my workplace for example, or the opposite.

Any idea what goes wrong?
The port 10000 appears open in the setting webpage of the Vps, and in file
**/etc/ssh/sshd_config** both ports 22 and 10000 are explicitly open too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The caveats were:

- open port `10000` on the cloud firewall
- do NOT listen on port `10000` with sshd
- add *'GatewayPorts yes'* in file **/etc/ssh/sshd_config**
- restart sshd on the Vps
- start sshd locally
- type `ssh -v -p some-ssh-open-port -i ~/.ssh/vps-key user-on-the-vps@vps-PUBLIC-ip -R 10000:localhost:22` (here, `22` is on the local computer and `10000` is on the vps) on computer1 with user1
- type `ssh -v -p 10000 -i ~/.ssh/vps-key user1-on-computer1@vps-PUBLIC-ip` from computer2 with user2

And this should be pretty much it. Some references:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AtuAdk4MwWw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=90d_whwkrNE
- https://superuser.com/questions/1194105/ssh-troubleshooting-remote-port-forwarding-failed-for-listen-port-errors
- https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/ssh-connection-refused/